# What is the best approxiamation of JavaFX "property" concept with ReactiveX / RxJava?

Tags: java, javafx, rx-java, subscriber

In JavaFX I can have a "property", which support the following operations

1. getting the value of property
2. setting the value of property
3. subscribing to property changes etc

I would like to use such a concept without dependency on Java FX and I think `RxJava` can be used. I thought about [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) but don't understand, how to perform `get` and `set` for it? Get is getting last value without subscribing and set in pushing new value without having subscribed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe related? https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX The two concepts are somewhat different: reactive programming relies on streams of events, which are ephemeral; JavaFX properties are more persistent objects.

Comment: Why though? What is the issue with only depending in the [javafx.base](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/module-summary.html) module to get this functionality?

Comment: @jewelsea The reason may be to keep the model free from any JavaFX specific stuff so that you can use the same model in another context where you may not have JavaFX available or where it does not really fit in. I had the same idea once and am now experimenting with Kotlin and its StateFlow as a common mechanism. Kotlin and StateFlow are, e.g., very popular in the new Jetpack Compose Android world and would be quite nice for JavaFX too.

Comment: [`BehaviorSubject`](https://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html) offers those features.